# POVM positive density matrix decomposition

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information

I have to prove that given a density matrix $\rho$ in a  finite d-dimensional Hilbert space $\mathcal{H}_d$, it always exists at least one informationally complete POVM measure $\{E_i\}_{i=1}^{d^2}$ such that
$$
\rho=\sum_{i=1}^{d^2} \alpha_i E_i,
$$
with $\alpha_i\geq 0$.

Without the last constraint on the $\alpha_i$ it is obvious, how can I prove it imposing the constraint $\alpha_i\geq 0$? Any idea?

Comment: What does "informationally complete" mean?

Comment: It means that the probability distribution $p^1_i=Tr(E_i \rho_1)$ (for $i=1,\dots,d^2$)  is different from $p^2_i=Tr(E_i \rho_2)$ (for $i=1,\dots,d^2$) whenever $\rho_1\neq \rho_2$. That is the measure is able to distinguish two states from the respective probability distributions.